# add navigation bar but there is no back button

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I created a table view and from there let say a user pressed a cell it will go to `ListTavleView` but the only problem right now is that whenever a user is in ListTableView there is not back button even thought i already embed a navigation controller

and i want the fist view navigation bar is small title second view navigation bar is large title

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fejL.png)

Below is my code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showList" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let items = dataManager.items[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ListTableViewController
            controller.item = items
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is my storybord setup**

[image]

**Navigation bar with no back button**

[image]

Comment: view controller is presenting or pushing?

Comment: change your segway method to push

Comment: Change the Segue to "Push"

Comment: i change Show(e.g Push)  there is no back button

Comment: Remove the navigation controller in the middle. Simply push the `ListTableViewController `.

Comment: I want one to be small navigation next view is large title

Comment: I want the above is the standard navigation bar next view is large title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing new NavigationController(say Nav.B) to the existing one(Nav.A).

Each navigation controller keeps different navigation stack. The back button is visible when you add viewcontroller to Navigation controller. Read more about [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller?changes=_4).

For your current scenario, you could delete the second navigation controller(i think it not essential) & connect direct segue to `ListTableViewController`

So this

```
let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ListTableViewController
```

becomes

```
let controller = segue.destination as! ListTableViewController
```

When you need large titles(available 11+), you can add this line in `viewDidLoad()`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

And if it needed only for this Viewcontroller, add in `viewWillDisappear()` or `viewDidDisappear()`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

Comment: I set the large title on the second view, but when I return to the first view, he will change to the large title

Comment: I would like to ask another question, There is no background on my first view. How do I restore my second view into a background?

Answer (score 3):

From the image it seems that view controller is added as a child view controller in current view controller.

There is not need to embedded navigation controller when a cell is pressed becoz there is already a navigation controller at start point so no need to create a new one.(If you present a view controller then you may need to embed navigation controller.)

So the solution is...

- Delete the navigation controller.

[image]

- Connect directly to the destination view controller without navigation controller as there is already.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I want the above is the standard navigation bar next view is large title

Comment: you can change properties of existing navigation bar.

Comment: I tried the above small view navigation bar next view is large title , when I return the title of the first page will become the large title

Comment: You need to set small title again when you go back.

Comment: how can i set ?

Answer (score 1):

it is better if you use pushViewController, just get a reference of the other view controller, it will always a back button since you are pushing threw navigation Controller here is a simple example:

```
let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleViewController") as! ExampleViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

as for the back button, the issue is with your hierarchy.
are you changing the left item of navigation bar in another view controller that might affect navigation bar in your destination view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to have navigation bar back button on next view, then just push the target view on navigation, it will show default navigation back button. No, need to any extra work.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "showList" {
  if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    let items = dataManager.items[indexPath.row]

    guard let controller = segue.destination as? ListTableViewController else {
      return
    }
    controller.item = items
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
  }
}}
```

And if you are pushing the viewcontroller with segue, then no need to add below line `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)`